# Php Validation inside if statement

Tags: php, validation, radio-button

I'd like to know if the following php validation is properly coded. It works, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it.

```
if(isset($_POST['account_type']) && $_POST['account_type']==2){

if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cnpj'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cnpj'])) > 32)) {
            $this->error['cnpj'] = $this->language->get('error_cnpj');
        }   
}
```

I need it like this because I have a hidden required field that is shown only to the customers who are applying for a corporate account. The field is shown after clicking a radio button. So I only need to validate that field [cnpj] when a customer clicks on the retailer account radio button with a value=2.

Thanks a lot.

Marvin M

Comment: What is the expected value of `$this->request->post['cnpj']`? int or string?

Comment: cnpj will be a string @LawrenceCherone

Comment: @Chandresh... and your comment is relevant to my question because...

Comment: .... because people won't feel inclined to help if you don't accept their answers. That's why.

Comment: 25% accept is unacceptable.  People more likely to help if the poster gives them points.  It's just a game to everyone.

Comment: Oh I see, The thing is I just started using this website, I only have like four questions and have given points to everybody, I guess what I missed is clicking on the "check"to accept an answer.Thanks for the the advise, I hadn't paid attention to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your code like below lines of code:

```
if($_POST['account_type']==2 && $this->formValidation()){

       // Do your next process what you want to do if all set

}else{

     return $this->error;

}
```

**// function for form validation**

```
function formValidation(){

if ((strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cnpj'])) < 3) || (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['cnpj'])) > 32)) {
            $this->error['cnpj'] = $this->language->get('error_cnpj');
        }   

}
```

**I think this would be a batter way to do all the form validation at server side. 
and also most of MVC structures follow this way.**